# Safari SharePoint Plugin not working

Tags: safari, microsoft-sharepoint

I have a strange problem with SharePoint and Safari.

- With 10.9 I was able to click on a file in a SharePoint site and it was opened in the corresponding Office application.
- After the upgrade to 10.10 the feature disappeared.
- With 10.11.0 it began to work again
- With 10.11.1 it stopped (and it is still not working with 10.11.2)

The SharePoint plugin seems installed:

[image]

But I have other machines with the same version (10.11.2) where it does work.

Comment: Based on previous empirical evidence… try 10.11.2  ;)

Comment: Hi I edited the question. It is still not working but not on all the machines. I don't think that the OS Version is the only reason. There must be something else: given that on other machines with the same version it works ...

Comment: Sorry, I was really just being flippant :) The only thing I could think would be to un/reinstall the plug, or make sure it's the latest version.